# Sharing custom subdomain on Facebook shows link to heroku app

Tags: facebook, heroku, dns

I recently deployed a website on Heroku and bought a domain name through OVH.

To link my custom domain to my Heroku app, I followed Heroku's doc here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-domain-with-a-subdomain

Everything works smoothly, I can access my website using my custom domain name.

The only issue is when I'm sharing a link from my website on Facebook, it shows the link to the heroku app in the preview: https://example.com/test becomes https://example.herokuapp.com in the preview.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Most likely because you redirect or set some og:url tag. You can debug the URL at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ to see what is going on

Comment: Smart, well done man! It was indeed the og:url tag. All good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone runs into the same type of issue, the link given by WizKid is super helpful: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

For me, the issue was an og:url tag that was set directly in Heroku through a CANONICAL_ROOT_URL config var.